# Handle Email Confirmation Redirect with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, vue-router, auth0

I'm working on project where the front-end is built with `Vue.js` and `Auth0` is being leveraged as the IDP.

When a user signs up and logs in for the first time, they get routed to `/verify-email` which contains a note asking them to check their email to verify their account.

Upon clicking on the email confirmation link, I am expecting the following request:

```json
http://localhost:3000/?supportSignUp=true
  &supportForgotPassword=true
  &email=john.doe%40exampleco.com
  &message=Your%20email%20was%20verified.%20You%20can%20continue%20using%20the%20application.
  &success=true#/register
```

As it pertains to SPAs, [Auth0's documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/email/email-templates#dynamic-redirect-to-urls) recommends handling the request as follow:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var qs = require('qs'); // to read query string params and stringify them

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  var route = req.query.route; // retrieve the route param that contains the SPA client side route user needs to be redirected to.

  delete req.query.route; // remove it from query params.
  res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#/' + route + '?' +  qs.stringify(req.query)); // Send a 302 redirect for the expected route
});

module.exports = router;
```

My project uses Vue-Router instead of Express to handle routes, so I followed the [relevant documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect) and did the following:

```js
{
  path: '/account-confirmed/:emailVerificationParams',
  redirect: to => {
    return { path: '/', query: { q: to.params.emailVerificationParams } }
  },
},
```

When a user confirms their account, they get sent to `/account-confirmed` which in turns should redirect them to `/`, which is a protected path, and should prompt them to enter their login credentials before accessing the application.

The redirect works fine when I test it manually in url by running the following:

```json
http://localhost:3000/?supportSignUp=true
  &supportForgotPassword=true
  &email=john.doe%40exampleco.com
  &message=Your%20email%20was%20verified.%20You%20can%20continue%20using%20the%20application.
  &success=true#/register
```

or:

```json
http://cf_distribution_url/?supportSignUp=true
  &supportForgotPassword=true
  &email=john.doe%40exampleco.com
  &message=Your%20email%20was%20verified.%20You%20can%20continue%20using%20the%20application.
  &success=true#/register
```

By running, I mean I am navigating to the urls by inputting them manually in the url address bar of my browser just as I would if I wanted to visit the sites of `Google`, `Facebook`, or `Stack Overflow`.

However, when I click on the email confirmation link, the redirect does not work. I get a 403 error as a response, whereas I'm expecting to be prompted to login again.

With that in mind, I have 2 questions:

1. What's wrong with my current redirect implementation?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: how is `path: '/account-confirmed/:emailVerificationParams',` at all related or even relevant to your manual test? I can't see it ... your statement `My project uses Vue-Router instead of Express` also makes no sense. It's like saying "My car is blue instead of electric"

Comment: sorry about the confusion, but i just made an edit to clarify. `account-confirmed` is the path a user initially get sent to after clicking on the email confirmation. all i'm trying to do with there is redirect to the home page.. i'm using vue-router to handle routes/paths in the app. the code sample provided leverages express, and since i'm not using express, i am basically trying to do the same thing with vue-router.

Comment: right, so you're using html5 history mode for vue router? and have set up your server correctly?

Comment: yes. app is hosted on s3 and distributed via cloudfront. when it comes to routing, everything works except this, so i'm confident my setup is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns, the issue was more with `Auth0` than it was with `Vue`. To resolve my issue, I just had to [Force Reauthentication in OIDC](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/max-age-reauthentication)